# dnf repoquery --best?

Tags: dependencies, dnf, download

Is there a `dnf repoquery --requires --resolve` option that makes it pick among dependency options the same as `dnf install` automatically does?

---

### Problem

I need to download an RPM and all its recursive dependencies for offline install, using a system that doesn't have `sudo` permissions and doesn't have exactly the same existing packages installed on it.  This means I can't simply use `dnf install --downloadonly --destdir` since it both requires `sudo` permissions and will only download the dependencies that aren't present on the current system (my target system has a more limited list of what's currently installed). So I have to recursively resolve all dependencies of a package manually, then pass that list of NEVRA format packages to the `dnf download` command.
However, I've found that when you use `dnf repoquery --requires --resolve {package}`, it will list every possible package that can provide the direct requirements and not just the "best" one like `dnf install {package}` automatically picks.

### Example of problem

For example, `dnf repoquery --requires --resolve curl` lists both `libcurl` and `libcurl-minimal`, which are conflicting packages and are expected to be options you choose between to satisfy the dependency. Tracing this, `dnf repoquery --deplist curl` lists that requirement `libcurl  >= {version}` can be satisifed by a few versions each of `libcurl-{version}` and `libcurl-minimal-{version}`.  This matches with the idea that `libcurl` and `libcurl-minimal` are alternative options to one another.
Compare this to when I run `dnf install curl`, and it just automatically picks the "best" `libcurl` dependency and chooses `libcurl-{version}`.

### Question

So since `dnf install {package}` somehow automatically picks which single provider of a requirement to install, how do I query to determine what that would be when I seemingly can't actually run `dnf install` directly due to `sudo` permission limits and needing to include dependencies that are already installed on the system I'm performing the download from?

---

I am also aware of the `dnf download --resolve --alldeps` (from dnf core plugins) that will resolve dependencies the same was as `dnf install` when resolving the requires, however I also need to prune dependencies and their branches for some things like `basesystem` and that's not possible with `dnf download`.

Comment: What are you attempting to achieve here? If sudoer rights aren't available on the machine, then the packages can't be installed. What's the point of just downloading them? Furthermore, the command that you are using finds dependents. If you want to find dependencies, then you need `yum deplist` or `dnf deplist`.

Comment: If you read my problem statement I explain. I'm downloading the packages for installation on a separate (airgapped) system. The target system is similar but not the same as the downloading system. The downloading system isn't installing anything so it doesn't have sudo permissions.

Comment: After 'dnf --deplist pkg' it appears the the first 'provider:' after the capability 'dependency:' might be the 'best' one you seek.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but you might consider creating your own duplicate repo on a filesystem then munge your /etc/dnf to point to it.  I believe the install CDs use(d) this method.

Comment: @mtalexan My mistake. With the way that have it written, it's a bit confusing as it doesn't specifically indicate that the system to which you are downloading the packages and the system on which they will be installed are two separate systems. In any event, the command that you need is still `dnf deplist <package>` or `yum deplist package`. As suggested, you can also just cut out the middle man and put the packages on a filesystem and add it as a repo for the system to which you want to install the packages. That removes an unneeded layer.

Comment: @NasirRiley Sorry, I described it better when I was telling someone else about it, but didn't want to unnecessarily edit here.

Comment: @stevea Is that always the case that it's first? If you have some reason to believe that it would be a good answer that would at least let me work around the problem.

Comment: @stevea How would the separate repo help? I still need to mine the dependency tree somehow to figure out what I need, is there something having it local adds?

Comment: Yes.  The local repo might have all the dependent packages, and then the target-system dnf can sort out the 'best'.